# Angular2 including angular2-moment 'require is not a function'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to bring in the [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) library to my angular2 project, but I can't seem to get SystemJS to cooperate.

```
<script src="lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="lib/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="lib/system-csp-production.src.js"></script>
<script src="lib/Reflect.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    map: {
      'angular2-moment': '/node_modules/angular2-moment',
    },
    packages: {
      '/node_modules/angular2-moment': {
        'main': 'index'
      }
  }
});
</script>

<script src="lib/angular2.js"></script>
<script src="lib/router.js"></script>
<script src="lib/http.js"></script>
<script src="lib/Rx.js"></script>

<script>
  System.import('app').catch(console.log.bind(console)); //loads my app
</script>
```

My application works as normal with this config, until I try to import from the angular2-moment library from within my application.

```
import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'angular2-moment';
```

Which results in the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function

Error: (SystemJS) http://website.dev/node_modules/angular2-moment/index.js did not call System.register or AMD define. If loading a global module configure the global name via the meta exports property for script injection support
```

Now at first glance this looked to me like SystemJS was expecting a different module type, but I've tried things like adding format:"esm" or "common" to the packages config to no avail. The error is correct (there is no System.register in the module, but rather an export function) but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

The index.js of angular2-moment looks like this:

```
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
__export(require('./CalendarPipe'));
__export(require('./DateFormatPipe'));
__export(require('./DurationPipe'));
__export(require('./FromUnixPipe'));
__export(require('./TimeAgoPipe'));
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Any steps in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your config for systemJS is correct. I hacked it into a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QcyPjTzXMzVCElB2eKWW?p=preview), with the paths to your local copy of angular2-moment replaced with the ones provided in the plunker from the angular2-moment github repo.

Is the index.html the only place you configure SystemJS or do you have a separate config.js file?

Comment: @MarkLanger I tried out the SystemJS config from the Plunker (using the npmcdn sources), and I get the same error. I don't have any config other than that in my index.html. I can see in the network tab it's loading the angular2-moment index.js properly, but is still expecting a different module format.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access 'angular2-moment' package using '/node_modules/angular2-moment', which seems to be incorrect,

Update your script config like below,

```
<script>
  System.config({
   map: { 'angular2-moment': '/node_modules/angular2-moment' },
   packages: {
      'angular2-moment': { 'main': 'index'  }
   }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you cloned angular2-moment, then compiled it to use the module type of your choice? Looks like it's doing a commonjs, but you have server-side script from node.